# Derivative of a definite integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linear-algebra

Could you help me to find the derivative of this definite integral?

$\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t{e^{A(t-s)}f(s)ds}$,

where $A$ and $f$ are matrices.

Basically I want to find the maximum/minimum points for the general solution of a system of linear differential equations:

$\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=0=\frac{d}{dt}[e^{At}x_o+\int_0^t{e^{A(t-s)}f(s)ds}]$,

where $x_o$ is the initial conditions vector.

Regards,

Marcos.

Comment: As the upper bound is not a constant, this should not be considered a definite integral.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite the integral as $\;\displaystyle\mathrm e^{At} \int_0^t\mathrm e^{-As}f(s)\,\mathrm d s $ and apply the *First fundamental theorem* of integral calculus:
\begin{align}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}\biggl(\mathrm e^{At} \int_0^t\mathrm e^{-As}f(s)\,\mathrm d s\biggr)&=A\,\mathrm e^{At} \int_0^t\mathrm e^{-As}f(s)\,\mathrm d s+\mathrm e^{At}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}\biggl(\int_0^t\mathrm e^{-As}f(s)\,\mathrm d s\biggr)\\
&=A\,\mathrm e^{At} \int_0^t\mathrm e^{-As}f(s)\,\mathrm d s+\mathrm e^{At}\,\mathrm e^{-At}f(t)\\
&=A\,\mathrm e^{At}\int_0^t\mathrm e^{-As}f(s)\,\mathrm d s+f(t).
\end{align}

Answer (score -1):

Your question makes sense but the motivation does not: these are vectors!

Aynways,
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left[e^{At}x_0+\int_0^t{e^{A(t-s)}f(s)\,ds}\right]=\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=Ax(t)+f(t).
$$